# Twig round number to max 8 decimal places

Tags: symfony, twig

Is it possible in Twig (used with Symfony2) to round number max to 8 decimal places OR less?

E.g.

- number is 10.0001 so I would like to display it as 10.0001 (not 10.00010000)
- number is 10.0000000000001 - display 10.0 (or 10)
- number is 10.00100000001 -> display 10.001

Function *number_format* allows only to set static number of decimal places (e.g. always 8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way for you to do this is a [Custom Twig Extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) implementing your logic.

That way you could use `{{ myNumber | round_number }}` and have the right rounded number to display.

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to get the result using `number_format` and `trim` like

```
{{ your_number | number_format(8) | trim (0) }}
```

That being said a custom twig extension like @bosam has recommended would probably be the easiest to use/remember in the future.